# Create Image from JCanvas (Java)

Tags: java, image, bufferedimage, jcanvas

just as the title suggests, I need to convert everything thats displayed in a program i.e. the Canvas to an Image or BufferedImage.

Comment: "jcanvas is a jQuery plugin.. " how is it used in Java code?

Comment: is it meant to be `java.awt.Canvas` ? if so, create a `BufferedImage`, create its `Graphics2D` and apply it to the `paint` method of `Canvas`